# VBA Concatenating columns based on other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to concat 2 columns from 2 different sheets.
When I run this code, Run-time error '13': Type mismatch will popout

```
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim sh4 As Worksheet

Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("S1")
Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("S2")
Set sh4 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Comparison")

If instr(sh4.Range("F1"),"URS") Then
   With sh1
        .Range(.Cells(2, sh4.Range("V4").Value), .Cells(2, sh4.Range("V4").Value).End(xlDown) & Range(.Cells(2, sh4.Range("W4").Value), .Cells(2, sh4.Range("W4").Value).End(xlDown))).Copy
   End with
```

Comment: `instr(1,sh4.Range("F1"),"URS")>0`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav sorry what do you mean? I believe my error lies on the `Range(.Cells(2, sh4.Range("V4").Value), .Cells(2, sh4.Range("V4").Value).End(xlDown) & Range(.Cells(2, sh4.Range("W4").Value), .Cells(2, sh4.Range("W4").Value).End(xlDown))).Copy`

since this part is highlighted

Comment: I think it's you havent closed your instr brackets.

Comment: oh sorry, this code is typed here. In my original code, on another computer, it is closed. Thanks for notifying me!